# css grid cards alignment

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to make something like this:

[image]

but I have something like this:

[image]

I'm using css grid and I don't know how to align this 3 last cards like here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8z7r.png)

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cards:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.cards {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.cards:nth-child(6) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row: 3 / 3;
}

.cards:nth-child(7) {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 3;
}

.cards:nth-child(8) {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: A http://jsbin.com or JSfiddle with your current code would help. It's hard to troubleshoot without the HTML too.

Comment: @Nelu in jsBin have you tried to use this Emmet `.wrapper>.cards{$}*8`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t6smzd5a/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yuroLem9/  If you want the second div to appear differently, maybe you should consider breaking it up into 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first row can use four columns to accommodate three items (one has double width).

The second row needs three columns to accommodate three items (all equal width).

So look for the common denominator: Since `3 x 4 = 12`, make a 12-column grid.

The three items in the first row can have their columns set to 6-3-3.

The three items in the second row can have their columns set to 4-4-4.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px 150px;
  max-width: 940px;
}

.cards:nth-child(1) { grid-column: 1 / 7;  grid-row: 1 / 3; }
.cards:nth-child(2) { grid-column: 7 / 10;  grid-row: 1 / 2; }
.cards:nth-child(3) { grid-column: 10 / 13; grid-row: 1 / 2; }
.cards:nth-child(4) { grid-column: 7 / 10;  grid-row: 2 / 3; }
.cards:nth-child(5) { grid-column: 10 / 13; grid-row: 2 / 3; }
.cards:nth-child(6) { grid-column: 1 / 5;  grid-row: 3 / 4; }
.cards:nth-child(7) { grid-column: 5 / 9;  grid-row: 3 / 4; }
.cards:nth-child(8) { grid-column: 9 / 13; grid-row: 3 / 4; }

.cards {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
  <div class="cards"></div>
</div>
```